# How to return an existing object with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

For the sake of example, I have a model for chemical elements

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :symbol, presence: true, uniqueness: true 
end
```

In `seeds.rb` I define all the known elements

```
Element.where(name: "hydrogen" symbol: "H").first_or_create
...
Element.where(name: "ununoctium" symbol: "Uuo").first_or_create
```

I define a factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :element do
    name "hydrogen" 
    symbol "H"
  end
end
```

Since the codebease depends on the presence of all seed elements, I prepare the test database with

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
```

Now my factory will never work

```
FactoryGirl.create(:element) #=> validation failed error
```

How do I write a factory in a way that first tries to find the creatable object in the database?

```
FactoryGirl.create(:element) #=> returns Element from db || Factory invocation
```

Comment: If you already seeded the DB for your tests, you can use that data right? Don't need a Factory for it then.

Comment: I would like to follow Rails' "convention over configuration" in that all test instances should be made via Factory in a predictable and maintainable way.

Comment: Then you should build the complete table using FactoryGirl and don't use the seed.

Comment: I recall something about not using seeds in specs. Any authoritative source pro this stance? Sadly, in this project, refactoring specs not to rely on seeds is not feasable.

Comment: I'm not saying you should create a seed... but you can use the structure for creating FactoryGirl's on the fly... but this would mean that for each test, the whole structure should be created. That would cost you some test performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of posterity, answering my own question with half a decade of experience under the belt.

Try using FactoryBot's `initialize_with` hook as [described in docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction).

```
factory :element do
  initialize_with do
    where(name: name, symbol: symbol).first_or_initialize
  end

  name "hydrogen" 
  symbol "H"
end
```

A spin on the idea is to forego the general factory and only have named factories for countable, uniqueness-constrained resources like chemical elements:

```
factory :element_hydrogen do
  initialize_with do
    where(name: "hydrogen", symbol: "H").first_or_initialize
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing this:

```
element = Element.find_by(name: "hydrogen") || FactoryGirl.create(:element, name: "hydrogen", symbol: "H")
```

Comment: Unacceptable because I would have to write this double logic every time I need Element instance in a test.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why create an object via factory if the object already exists in database? If you want to use factory only why not put your factory calls in your seeds.rb (although it's not [recommended](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory_girl-for-seed-data))?